# center align two divs with image on right

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need to center the arrow image to the right at all times. Currently the text is centered, but when it is two lines the imagediv is not centered.

```html
<div id="holding" style="margin:auto; position:relative; overflow: hidden; max-width: 666px; border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEB;">
  <div class="job   teamCleanString  '   locationCleanString  '   commitmentCleanString  '">'
    <div style="float:left;">
      <a class="job-title" style="color:#FF4F5D;" href="'  link  '" ">'  title  '</a></div>'           
    <div id="imagediv " style=" right:5px;float:right;position:absolute; ">
    <a href=" '  link  ' ""><img border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b3b89dea339e60649183848/5b3bc02bedb57a5c5b6b9a38_small-grey-arrow.svg" width="25" height="25"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both; font-size:1px;"></div>
</div>
```

[image]
I tried using the following on the imagediv but sometime the text was two lines and not one so it caused problems:

```
 position:absolute;top:50%;
```

But it did not work. It is supposed to look like this, and I think the solution will be easy but I am struggling. Please help.

[image]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to center, the arrow icons?

Comment: yes need that arrow centered

Comment: again, please either make your code more readable or create a codepen/jsfiddle. also, there are errors in your code...

Comment: try nested flexbox's

Comment: i edited your post and set your code into a snippet. feel free to edit it again to provide an example of what you have (result and issue). As you can see, your code doesn't show much of your trouble ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is your friend.

Using the current Bootstrap 4 for the class sugar, your markup gets even simpler as well, and it's easy to see what your intent is right here

```
<div id="holding">
  <div class="job d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <a class="job-title" style=";" href="#"> machine learning engineer  </a>
    <a class="imgcontainer" href="#"><img border="0 " alt="W3Schools " src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b3b89dea339e60649183848/5b3bc02bedb57a5c5b6b9a38_small-grey-arrow.svg " width="25 " height="25 "></a>
  </div>
  <div class="job d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <a class="job-title" style=";" href="#"> a really long job description linktext </a>
    <a class="imgcontainer" href="#"><img border="0 " alt="W3Schools " src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b3b89dea339e60649183848/5b3bc02bedb57a5c5b6b9a38_small-grey-arrow.svg " width="25 " height="25 "></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and your css would look like

```
#holding {
  margin:auto; 
  position:relative; 
  max-width: 666px; 
  border: 1px solid #EBEBEB; 
}
.job {
  border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
  padding: 0.33em 0.66em;
}
.job-title {
  color:#FF4F5D;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

demo codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXbWxY

you may find https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-animated-guide-to-flexbox-d280cf6afc35 to be useful in helping you to understand how flexbox actually works. It can be a little confusing at first, but it's relatively simple.

Comment: there you go :)

Answer (score 1):

I would set display:flex and align-items:center in your css like so:

```css
job {
      display: flex;
      align-items:center;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="holding" style="margin:auto; position:relative; overflow: hidden; max-width: 666px; border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEB;">
      <div class="job   teamCleanString   locationCleanString  commitmentCleanString ">
        <div style="float:left;">
          <a class="job-title" style="color:#FF4F5D;" href='  link  '>  title 1  </a></div>           
        <div id="imagediv " style=" right:5px;float:right;position:absolute; ">
          <a href=" '  link  ' "">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M7.5 4.5L6.44 5.56 9.88 9l-3.44 3.44L7.5 13.5 12 9z"/></svg>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both; font-size:1px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="holding" style="margin:auto; position:relative; overflow: hidden; max-width: 666px; border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEB;">
      <div class="job   teamCleanString   locationCleanString  commitmentCleanString ">
        <div style="float:left;">
          <a class="job-title" style="color:#FF4F5D;" href='  link  '>  title 2</br>with two lines  </a></div>           
        <div id="imagediv " style=" right:5px;float:right;position:absolute; ">
          <a href=" '  link  ' "">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M7.5 4.5L6.44 5.56 9.88 9l-3.44 3.44L7.5 13.5 12 9z"/></svg>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both; font-size:1px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="holding" style="margin:auto; position:relative; overflow: hidden; max-width: 666px; border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEB;">
      <div class="job   teamCleanString   locationCleanString  commitmentCleanString ">
        <div style="float:left;">
          <a class="job-title" style="color:#FF4F5D;" href='  link  '>  title 3  </a></div>           
        <div id="imagediv " style=" right:5px;float:right;position:absolute; ">
          <a href=" '  link  ' "">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M7.5 4.5L6.44 5.56 9.88 9l-3.44 3.44L7.5 13.5 12 9z"/></svg>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both; font-size:1px;"></div>
    </div>
```

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/58ar1syb/12/

Comment: arrows are not centered

Comment: Sorry, the run code snippet appears to not get the css. If you follow the link to the js fiddle you can see it working